# SAS EG How to compare cell values in an array loop?

Tags: loops, sas

I am currently trying to compare cell values on the same row over multiple columns, but having issues with referencing the correct cells.

My data currently is this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | d | e | f |
| a | b | c | d | e | e |
| a | b | c | d | d | d |

I would like to compare col{i} to col{i+1} and drop values when repeated to give:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | d | e | f |
| a | b | c | d | e | - |
| a | b | c | d | - | - |

My current code is:

```
data want;
set have;
array c{*} col;
do i = 1 to dim(c);
do j = i+1;
if c{i} = c{j} then .;
else c{i};
end;
end;
run;
```

TIA

Comment: What if you have consequtive letters that are the same in the middle of the sequence?

Comment: @draycut so the text is addresses and after testing the only sections of address that are the same is the last two columns, but the position of the last two columns changes depending on how long the addresses are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data want;
  set have;
  array c{*} col:;
  do i =  dim(c) to 2 by -1;   *no reason to check #1;
    if c{i} = c{i-1} then call missing(c{i});   *if identical to prior, clear out;
  end;
run;
```

You don't need two loops - just one - as you're just checking the record "before" (or "after", but "before" is easier to mentally comprehend, at least for me).  Start on 2, check the one prior, and if identical, clear it out.

Importantly, this goes in reverse order (so it gets the `d` situation above) - if you go left to right, it won't get the last d as it won't compare to the right one.

Comment: This has worked thank you. Good thinking to go from right to left. Also, is there a good resource for array syntax? I feel like the array syntax I've come across is different from that in non-array data steps.

Comment: An ARRAY in a SAS data step is just a tool to allow referencing variables via an index into a list of variables.  This problem is a good example of when using an ARRAY can simplify code.

Comment: Is `array c{*} col` the same as `array c{*} col:` ?

Comment: It's not, and it should probably have the `:` - I left that alone as the OP had it like that, but it's a good point.

Answer (score 0):

For the case of data containing multiple segments of repeated values and wanting only unique consecutive values you will need to track an insertion index.

Example: Variable **j** tracks the insertion point

```
data have;
input (col1-col6) ($) @1 (kol1-kol6) ($);
format col: kol: $1.;
datalines;
a b c d e f
a b c d e e 
a b c d d d
a a b b c c
a a b b a a
. b b b c d
a a . . c c
run;

data want(keep=col: kol:);
  set have;
  array c col1-col6;
  
  j = 1;
  do i = 2 to dim(c);
    if c(i) ne c(j) then do;
      j = j + 1;
      if i ne j then do;
        c(j) = c(i);
        call missing(c(i));
      end;
    end;
  end;
  do j = j+1 to i-1;
    call missing(c{j});
  end;
run;
```

[image]

For the case of wanting only unique values of the array, you can use a bubble sorting comparison approach when the number of elements is smallish, say <10.

```
/* uniqueness via a bubbly search */

data want_b;
  set have;
  array c col1-col6;
  j=0;
  do i = 1 to dim(c);
    if missing(c{i}) then continue;
    do k = 1 to j; * bubble, bubble;
      if c{k} = c{i} then do;
        call missing(c{i});
        leave;
      end;
    end;
    if missing(c{i}) then continue;
    j = j + 1;
    if j < i then do;
      c{j} = c{i};
      call missing(c{i});
    end;
  end;
run;
```

[image]

When the number of elements increases you can use a hash to be more efficient whilst ensuring uniqueness.

```
/* uniqueness via hash lookup */

data want_h(keep=col: kol:);
  set have;
  array c col1-col6;

  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash v();
    length value $20;  * must be at least as long as longest of c{*} variable ;
    v.defineKey('value');
    v.defineData('i');
    v.defineDone();
    call missing(value);
  end;

  j = 0;
  do i = 1 to dim(c);
    if not missing(c{i}) then if v.check(key:c{i}) ne 0 then do;
      v.add(key:c{i},data:i);
      j = j + 1;
      if i ne j then
        c(j) = c(i);
    end;
  end;
  do j = j+1 to dim(c);
    call missing(c{j});
  end;
  v.clear();
run;
```